# Play Framework - Ebean - No ScalarType registered for class "class name"

Tags: java, mysql, orm, persistence, ebean

I built some tables in MySQL database, using persistence API and Ebean by representing the custom Java Objects as tables. Now, I try to recover the stored entries, by passing as arguments in the Ebean.find() queries the objects I want, but `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` is thrown every time.

---

Let me explain the hierarchies and structure:

There is a **Machine** class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "MACHINE_TYPE")
public class Machine extends Model
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long _machineID;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String _name;

    @Column(name = "info")
    private String _info;

    // rest of code
}
```

With two subclasses. A **Server** class extending **Machine** as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "machine")
@DiscriminatorValue("Server")
public class Server extends Machine
{
   @Column(name = "ip")
   private String _ip;

   @Column(name = "port")
   private Integer _port;

   @Column(name = "user_name")
   private String _userName;

   @Column(name = "password")
   private String _password;

   @Column(name = "clock")
   private Integer _clock;

   @Column(name = "ram")
   private Integer _ram;

   // rest of code
}
```

And a **Container** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "machine")
@DiscriminatorValue("Container")
public class Container extends Machine
{
@Column(name = "dockerID", unique = true)
   private String _dockerID;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "host", insertable = true, updatable = true)
   private Server _host;

   @Column(name = "currentSize")
   private String _currentSize;

   @Column(name = "additionalInfo")
   private String _additionalInfo;

   @Column(name = "last_login")
   private String _lastLogin;

   // rest of code
}
```

---

This code, builds a machine table in MySQL database as follows:

```
`machine` (
  `machine_type` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `info` mediumtext,
  `dockerID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currentSize` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additionalInfo` text,
  `last_login` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `port` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clock` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ram` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq_machine_dockerID` (`dockerID`),
  KEY `ix_machine__host_4` (`host`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_machine__host_4` FOREIGN KEY (`host`) REFERENCES `machine` (`id`)
)
```

Which seems correct. But, if I add an entry into the DB and try to execute

```
...
Server server = Server.getServerByName(serverName); // this returns a Server object correctly
List<Container> testCase = Ebean.find(Container.class)
                    .where()
                    .eq("host", server)
                    .findList(); // this throws the exception
```

I got a `PersistenceException` saying:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No ScalarType registered for class com.project.models.Server
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:158)
    rest of the StackTrace
```

Even when I try to change the query with

```
List<Container> testcase = Ebean.find(Container.class)
                    .where()
                    .eq("host", server.getMachineId()) // pass the serverID
                    .findList();
```

I got another exception denoting:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Column 'host' in where clause is ambiguous 
Bind values:[1] 
Query was:
select t0.machine_type c0, t0.id c1, t0.name c2, t0.info c3, t0.dockerID c4, t0.currentSize c5, 
t0.additionalInfo c6, t0.last_login c7, t1.machine_type c8, t0.host c9 from machine t0 
left outer join machine t1 on t1.id = t0.host and t1.machine_type = 'Server'  
where t0.machine_type = 'Container'  and host = ?
```

---

Any help, at least to what direction to follow will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some testing, I found out that if you want to access the Database tables with objects you need to follow some rules in your object mapping and obviously I didn't. Also nowhere in the documentation I could be able to find this. This solution is result of fail and try.

---

First, the name of the variables must be the same as the names of the columns! If I change the `Container.class` and `Server.class` variables into:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "host", insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Server host; // notice the name is the same as the column name
```

all works fine and I can pass `Server.class` objects in the queries like:

```
Ebean.find(Container.class)
      .where()
      .eq("host", server)
      .findList();
```

So to map object entities, column names must be exactly as variable names and vice versa.

---

Secondly, and as far as I read in documentation, we can specify the target entity in the `@ManyToOne` annotation as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Server.class) // explicitly specify the target class
@JoinColumn(name = "host", insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Server host;
```

this although is not the main problem in my case, because Java reads the class type of the `host` field and pass the target entity automatically. But better be safe here.